# How to install the lcm on ubuntu arm 12.04

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I want to install the lcm on  ubuntu arm 12.04 armel. Now I have downloaded the lcm-0.9.0.zip.I did as the following on the arm:

```
$ unzip  lcm-0.9.0.zip
$cd  lcm-0.9.0
$chmod +x configure
$ ./configure
```

than it shows below

```
checking build system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi                                                                                                                                                                            
  checking host system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi                                                                        
  checking target system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi                                                                      
  checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c                                                                     
  checking whether build environment is sane... configure: error: newly created file is older than distributed files!              
  Check your system clock
```

How can I do.Is there any way to install lcm on the arm that can be reference. Please help me .Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197836/how-to-install-the-lcm-on--ubuntu-arm-12.04/) by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see how this is a ROS issue, but since the answer is in the question... here it goes:

*Check your system clock*

Make sure that your system clock is configured with the current date and time (either manually or using ntpdate).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0